# The rate of convergence for finite difference methods for Poisson's equation with piecewise constant data

Tags: pde, convergence, poisson

I am solving the following PDE;

$$
\nabla^2 u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = \rho,
$$

where $\rho(0.5,0.5) = 2$ (zero elsewhere), $0\leq x,y\leq1$ and the boundaries will satisfy the condition $u = 0$.

I am solving by finite differences using both a 5 point second order stencil and a 9 point fourth order stencil. It is my understanding that the solution to this PDE is the zero function and this is what I am using to calculate rates of convergence. I have used various error measures including the average difference, max difference and the value at the point $(0.5,0.5)$.

For each error measure I am getting convergence rates of approximately order 2 for both stencils, is there a reason why the fourth order stencil would not converge with order 4?

This is a repeat of a question I asked on MSE - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073945/the-rate-of-convergence-for-finite-difference-methods-for-poissons-equation-wit/1074255#1074255

Although the answers there have helped a lot I would appreciate anyone who could elaborate a little further?

Comment: The answer you got on MSE looks good to me, why post a duplicate question? That said, have you absolutely made sure your implementation is correct? When you want to test a method's implementation, you should start by picking some known functions $u(x,y)$, finding the corresponding b.c. and r.h.s. $\rho$, and comparing with numerical approximations.

Comment: No I am not completely certain...mainly because it does not converge how I expected! I am trying to test it on a known solution but I am having issues deciding how to deal with boundary points since the nine point stencil extends out two nodes...Duplicate question is because it was suggested to do so...

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068) about cross-posting; it's a slight breach of etiquette. For boundary points, if you *know* an exact solution, set the boundary points and the points just beyond the boundary to their exact known values; this gives you the linear equations you need to solve. An alternative is to use a smaller stencil at points next to the boundary, so that no extra ghost points are needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's examine the one-dimensional three-point stencil case in detail,
because I think it's important to be clear just how this behaviour
arises, and what it means to set a point to a certain value in a
finite-difference grid when the underlying function is
discontinuous. The equation will be
$$ u''(x) = \rho(x). $$
Instead of using the interval $[-1,1]$ with discontinuity at
$\frac12$, I will use the interval $[-\frac12,\frac12]$ with the
discontinuity placed at $0$. The grid size will be $h$, and I will only have to consider the interval $[-\frac h2,\frac h2]$ around the grid point $0$.

First, in a finite-difference approximation, we approximate
$$ u''(0) = \frac{\hat u(-h) - 2\hat u(0) + \hat u(h)}{h^2} $$
and solve
$$ \frac{\hat u(-h) - 2\hat u(0) + \hat u(h)}{h^2} = \hat \rho(0). $$
(Here the variables with hats are the numerical approximations on the
grid to the variables without hats.)

But this is a very bad specification of the problem, because your
function $\rho(0) = 2$ at $x=0$, and $\rho(x) = 0$ everywhere else, is
discontinuous. In particular, if we shift the grid point $0$ to either
side by some tiny amount $\epsilon$, the numerical solution changes
entirely and becomes exactly zero.
This means that this is a terribly misspecified problem.

We can make sense of it by
converting it to an equivalent finite-volume formulation, where it
will make much more sense.

In a finite-volume method, we solve
$$ \int_{-h/2}^{h/2} u''(x)\,dx = \int_{-h/2}^{h/2}\rho(x)\,dx, $$
by picking $u(x)$ to be a suitable approximation to the unknown
function. Let's pick, on the interval $[-\frac h2,\frac h2]$ the approximation
$$ u(x) =  \hat u(-h) \phi(x+h) + \hat u(0) \phi(x) + \hat u(h) \phi(x-h), $$
where $\phi(x)$ is the basis function
$$ \phi(x) = \max\left(1-\frac{|x|}{h}, 0\right), $$
(it's a piecewise linear function that goes from $0$ at $-h$ to $1$ at
$0$ to $0$ at $+h$, thus interpolating between grid points.). The approximation $u(x)$ is a weighted sum of three basis functions that look like this:

[image: Basis functions]

We can then compute
$$ \phi''(x) = \frac1h\delta(h-|x|) - \frac2h \delta(x), $$
so that the approximation to the integral is
$$ \int_{-h/2}^{h/2} u''(x) = \frac{\hat u(-h) -2\hat u(0)+\hat
  u(h)}{h}, $$
and the finite-volume approximation to our equation becomes
$$ \frac{\hat u(-h) -2\hat u(0) + \hat u(h)}{h} = \int_{-h/2}^{h/2}
\rho(x)\,dx = h \hat \rho(0). $$

There are two important things here. First, this is *equivalent* to
the finite-difference formulation in that we end up solving the same
equations. Second, the discontinuity in $\rho$ is given a very precise
meaning: when we use the value $2$ for $\hat \rho(0)$, we are saying
that this is the average value of $\rho$ on the interval $[-h/2,h/2]$:
$$2 = \hat\rho(0) = \frac1h  \int_{-h/2}^{h/2} \rho(x)\,dx.$$
This interpretation is not available in the finite-difference
formulation. It is also not so sensitive to the location of the discontinuity: if the discontinuity were at some small distance $\epsilon$ away from $0$, the average value would be almost the same, but the value at $0$ might be completely different.

But if we say that $2$ is the average value of $\rho$ near the grid
point, we can then go back and compute the exact solution of the
equation with the right-hand side given by
$$ \tilde \rho(x) = 2[-h/2 < x < h/2]. $$
(We pick a function of our own choice that gives the right average.)
In this case, the exact solution will be
$$ \tilde u(x) = 2 \int_{-h/2}^{h/2} G(x; u)\,du \approx 2h G(x;
0), $$
in terms of the Green function for the Poisson equation. In the two-dimensional case it will be
$$ \approx 2h^2 G(x, y; 0, 0), $$
as in the other (correct) answer on MSE.

Finally, the outcome of all this is that when you say that you compare
your numerical approximate solution with the exact solution $u(x)=0$,
this is wrong. The exact solution should not be zero, it should be
$$ \approx 2h^2 G(x, y; 0,0). $$
It therefore should make perfect sense that the fourth-order solution does not converge to zero with order $4$: it *should* converge to the correct solution, which is not zero but has magnitude of order $O(h^2)$.

If you *do* want to get zero as the numerical solution and compare with the mathematical solution, you should set $\hat\rho(0)$ to be the average value of $\rho$, which is $0$, not $2$.

The fact that the exact solution depends on the chosen grid size indicates that this is not a good way to check whether you implemented the method correctly. A very straightforward technique known as the method of manufactured solutions is better for this.

Comment: I really appreciate the work you have put into this answer, it has made things much clearer for me. The method I am using does converge as expected (order 4) for a manufactured solution with no discontinuities - so I am happy that my implementation is correct. In terms of this particular source term - the reason it seems to be converging to the zero function is because of the scaling of the greens function by $h^2$ which in the limit is zero? I still have a bit of work to do to fully understand the convergence I am seeing but I am much closer to being able to do this - thanks again!!

Comment: @JoshGreenhalgh [Upvote answers that you find helpful.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) Yes, if the exact solution is $O(h^2)$, it will converge to zero as $h\to0$, making it look like you see your numerical method converges to the "right" solution at order 2.

Comment: I am not yet worthy to upvote...but it is done in spirit!

Comment: @Kirill Beautiful ! +1

Answer (score 0):

Think about what "second order" and "fourth order" approximations actually mean. A first order method can exactly reproduce a first order (linear) function, a second order can reproduce a quadratic, etc.

So say if the exact solution to a given problem is linear - if so, a 100th order method won't give you any benefit over a 1st order method, because both can exactly represent the solution. I suspect this might be a similar case with your zero function solution. Try something with a sinusoidal forcing term or boundary condition.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, which is about a very specific right-hand side; the answer shouldn't be "try a different r.h.s.". Can you explain the observed results directly?

Comment: The mathexchange answer is effectively the same thing, just with some rigor and without my hand-waving. He showed the actual answer to the problem is itself $O(h^2)$. If the analytical answer to a problem is $O(h^2)$ then an $O(h^4)$ approximation will never be any better than an $O(h^2)$ approximation. The answer really is "try a different RHS" or "try different BCs", because the example given won't show a difference between 2nd and higher order schemes. Truncation errors will be identically 0.

Comment: The question is "is there a reason why the fourth order stencil would not converge with order 4?", which I interpret as asking about this precise r.h.s. I agree that if the question were "how should I test these methods", the answer would be "try a better r.h.s.".

Comment: "is there a reason why the fourth order stencil would not converge with order 4?" - yes, and the reason is that the actual solution is order 2, so higher convergence is not possible. One can write out a mathematical proof, but it should be intuitively obvious. If you're trying to approximate a function which is a straight line, a tenth order approximation cannot be more accurate than a first order one, since the first order would be exact.

Comment: The fact that if the solution is order 2 a method of order 4 wound not show any improvement is clear to me...however why the 'solution' is order 2 is not! But thanks anyway...my method does converge with order 4 for a problem involving a trigonometric source term just not this one

Comment: It'd take me some work to figure out how your mathexchange answer got to $O(h^2)$, but suffice to say that (a) a point source on a finite grid domain is actually an average over a region, and not an actual point as it'd be in a continuous domain, and (b) "exact solutions" on discrete meshes might not be the same as the "exact solution" in a continuous domain, especially when dealing with odd things like singularities.